# Windows Phone 8.1 Admob interstitial disappears on touch

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, admob, interstitial

I have implemented Admob in my Windows app, a both banner and  interstitialAd. Banner works kind of (when clicking it in windows the text in the ad sometimes gets selected instead of it firing the ad).
When the  interstitialAd shows up, which it does fine, when the ad is clicked/touched it just disappears. It does direct the user to the ad site. It just goes back to the app.

My code:

```
Public Sub showIntAd()
    Dim IntAd As InterstitialAd = New InterstitialAd(INT_AD_UNIT)
    Dim AdRequest As AdRequest = New AdRequest()

    'AdRequest.ForceTesting = True

    AddHandler IntAd.ReceivedAd, AddressOf OnAdReceived
    AddHandler IntAd.FailedToReceiveAd, AddressOf adFailed

    IntAd.LoadAd(AdRequest)

End Sub

Public Sub loadBannerAd(adReq As AdView)
    adReq.Format = AdFormats.SmartBanner

    adReq.AdUnitID = BANNER_AD_UNIT
    Dim AdRequest = New AdRequest()

    'AdRequest.ForceTesting = True
    'BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    adReq.LoadAd(AdRequest)
End Sub



Private Sub adFailed(sender As Object, e As AdErrorEventArgs)
    'DO NOTHING
End Sub

Private Sub OnAdReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AdEventArgs)
    Dim intAd As InterstitialAd = CType(sender, InterstitialAd)
    intAd.ShowAd()
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my splash screen i have the following:

AddHandler Touch.FrameReported, AddressOf screenTapped

The sub screenTapped dismisses the splash screen. This code seems to affect the Admob InterstitialAd for some reason, although the ad is called on the second screen. I removed this code and its working fine now.